# How to make sure which program is run behind a terminal command

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

If I run

```
ipython notebook
```

in terminal

it reports

```
Could not start notebook. Please install ipython-notebook
```

But I am sure the notebook is indeed install by

```
conda install ipython-notebook
```

because

```
conda install ipython-notebook
```

gives me

```
Fetching package metadata: ..
Solving package specifications: .
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/a/anaconda:
#
ipython-notebook          2.3.1                    py27_0
```

so I guess the command line bunded to a wrong location.

So how can I figure out which binary or directory the command line pointed to?

Answer (score 0):

I am not terribly familar with conda, but looking at the [description](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/conda/3.7.0) tells me it is some soft of package management tool. One of its strengths, like the `virtualenv` package, is that you can have completely different environments (installations) of python packages. This allows you to have a separate set of packages for different requirements, for example.

One drawback is that the different environments need to be *activated* so that the packages contained therein can be used.

For conda and your particular case, it seems that:

```
cd ~
source activate anaconda
```

Will activate the environment stored in $HOME/anaconda/.

Not that conda tells you where the environment is stored:

```
Fetching package metadata: ..
Solving package specifications: .
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/a/anaconda:
#
ipython-notebook          2.3.1                    py27_0
```